# TextInput: Unexpected cursor movement when changing font_size

Tags: python, kivy

In Kivy Text Input, cursor moves to the text end every time when changing font_size:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = """
TextInput
    on_touch_down: self.font_size+=1
"""
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)

MyApp().run()
```

Is there a way how to fix or workaround this behavior of TextInput?

Answer (score 0):

- Declare a class attribute, `prev_cursor` in `class MyApp`
- Implement a method `reset_cursor()` to restore `prev_cursor` to TextInput's cursor
- `on_touch_down` event, save current cursor position
- `on_touch_up` event, use Kivy `Clock.schedule_once()` to invoke method `reset_cursor()`

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = """
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock

TextInput:
    on_touch_down:
        app.prev_cursor = self.cursor
        self.font_size += 1
    on_touch_up:
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: app.reset_cursor(), 0.1)

"""


class MyApp(App):
    prev_cursor = ()

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)

    def reset_cursor(self):
        self.root.cursor = self.prev_cursor


MyApp().run()
```

Comment: The problem still exists at least on Linux (ubuntu): cursor moves to last text character every time when changing font_size

Comment: It runs fine on Linux (Buster) and Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

Comment: Could you try to move the editing cursor to the beginning of the line using mouse, for example? Just click there.

The cursor moves to the end of the line always, this is the problem I want to solve

Comment: Sorry to have misunderstood the problem. Please check the updated post.